# Open with linux context menu opens the app twice QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have done the command line processing in my QT application so I can set it as default for audio files. But while I try to open an audio file with my QT application again, it opens a new window.

Is there a way to make it so it opens the new file in the same window, if that file is open from a file manager with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a file  whenever your app starts. Proceed or exit according to the contents of the file.

or  try make your app single instance?

`https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication`